# HierarchicalDataTemplate and XDocument

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I have a XML Datastructure which looks like this:

```
<PersonData Id="1">
  <FirstName>Tom</FirstName>
  <LastName>Test</LastName>
  <Sex>M</Sex>
</PersonData>
```

I want to display this information in a `TreeView`, I've created a custom HierarchicalDataTemplate like this:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="Template" DataType="PersonData">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Margin="0" Text="Id:" />
                <TextBlock Margin="5,0,0,0" Text="{Binding XPath=@Id}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </UserControl.Resources>
```

And using this in a TreeView like this:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding XmlDocument, Mode=TwoWay}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Template}" Height="200"/>
```

But nothing shows up, in the Treeview. What am I doing wrong? How can I display properties such as FirstName, LastName, and Sex?

Thanks!

Comment: How do you create `XmlDocument`? Is it `XDocument`?

Comment: @dkozl Yes, it is a `XDocument`

Comment: In such case [Binding.XPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.xpath(v=vs.110).aspx) states: _LINQ to XML objects XDocument and XElement do not use XPath. For details, see [How to: Bind to XDocument, XElement, or LINQ for XML Query Results](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc165615(v=vs.110).aspx)._